# The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types; no solution found

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

any help on this one would greatly be appreciated.
I've reviewed related questions and am seriously struggling.

Asp.net C# EF6 project giving me the following error (I have about 15 classes that are ambiguous):

```
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'AgencyType'. Previously found CLR type 'TBH.Domain.Model.CMS.AgencyType', newly found CLR type 'TBH.Data.EF.MoveUsers.AgencyType'.
```

These two namespaces are already in different assemblies, but it doesn't matter because the main project references both of them.

TBH.Domain.Model.CMS.AgencyType  (ObjectContext)

TBH.Data.EF.MoveUsers.AgencyType (DbContext, T4)

Underneath it all is an EDMX file.

I've tried "customannotation" solution, but couldn't get it to work.  Also not too keen on managing edmx manual changes.

Trying to avoid manually changing the class names.

Is there any solution I'm overlooking that I can try?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using Code First from an Existing Database will remove the EDMX entirely. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David Browne.

I ended up deciding to just rename the classes of my tt file and cross my fingers that I don't have to manually regenerate that thing in the future.